# Wordpress - Logout redirection based on role

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to determine how I can redirect users upon logout, to a URL defined by their role. Simply put, I want to redirect admins (as well as editors) that logout to a different URL, than subscribers / privileged users.

I'm using the following code to redirect users at logout right now, but this redirects everyone. Any insight as to how I can have a different redirect based on their account role, would be great!

```
/**
 * Redirect to custom login page after the user has been logged out.
*/
public function redirect_after_logout() {
    $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-login?logged_out=true' );
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_logout', array( $this, 'redirect_after_logout' ) );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im not sure didnt test but you can use user roles with if else statement

```
function redirect_after_logout() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) { 
        $url = '/';
    } else { 
        $url = 'member-login?logged_out=true';
    }
    $redirect_url = home_url( $url );
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_logout', array( $this, 'redirect_after_logout' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the doucumentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/ how to check if current user has the specified capability.

Here is a sample:

```
if (!current_user_can('edit_posts') && !is_admin()) {
    $redirect_url = site_url();
} else {
    $redirect_url = '/wp-login.php';
}
function wpdocs_redirect_after_logout()
{

    global $redirect_url;
    wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'wpdocs_redirect_after_logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function redirect_after_logout( $user_id ) {
    $user       = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user_roles ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout' );
```